# NetBeans Profiler

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Does NetBeans profiler work with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as I know, but there are no problems whatsoever on using it side by side with Eclipse. That's what I've done when I needed a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the profiler from VisualVM (included in your JDK), which is also based the NetBeans profiler.